# Excessive Virtual Bytes allocated for 64bit w3wp process on .Net 4.0

Tags: asp.net

I'm in need of some assistance trying to explain why an application running on 64bit Win2008 R2 under a .Net 4.0 app pool would have 9.5GB of virtual memory allocated to it.

I was tasked with finding a comfortable value to set the IIS Virtual Memory Limit recycling flag to since "0" is an IA concern (Government requirement). But since I've started looking into the subject it's gotten more and more confusing.

I started my research and found the .Net segment sizes for .Net 4.x on 64bit OS is [1280MB per logical core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2015/08/21/asp-net-segment-heap-sizes-or-how-much-virtual-memory-my-web-app-will-need/). So after doing the math our dev server should have needed about 2.6GB of virtual memory for JUST Asp.Net to stand up. However once I started monitoring w3wp through performance monitor the Virtual Bytes for the process is at 9.6GB. Which obviously is far more than I expected, or can explain.

Initially I expected a memory leak or some crazy amount of data being pushed onto the heap. So I  monitored the process for about 30 minutes and the Virtual Bytes and Working Set where not growing like a memory leak would (the w3pw process would start, run for about a minute, and then the Virtual Bytes would shoot up, then remain consistent). Next,  I stood up the template MVC website and pointed it at IIS and w3pw is still having 9.4GB of allocated Virtual Bytes.

So I've went back to researching, but it seems like everyone that has encountered this issue either sets the limit back to zero, or just leaves it at an outrageously high value and moves on with life. I'm hoping someone out there can point me towards an answer as to why w3wp is being allocated so much Virtual Memory.